# Shared Memory slows down the blurring operation compared to the one without shared memory

Tags: cuda, gaussianblur, gpu-shared-memory

When I use shared memory in my Gaussian blur kernel, the execution time is slower than without shared memory. Could you help me to resolve this issue?

The execution time using shared memory is 0.27 ms however, the execution time without using shared memory is 0.18 ms.

In addition to that, the number of inactive threads is almost two times higher than without using shared memory.

```
__global__ 
void gaus_xdirection_shared(float *in_channel, float *output_channel, float *gaussian_kernel, const int width, const int height, int k){
    int row = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    __shared__ float columns[1024];

    int b_row = threadIdx.y;
    int b_col = threadIdx.x;
    int b_width = blockDim.x;

    if(row < height && col < width){
        int p = row * width + col;

        //Load starts
        int b_p = b_row * b_width + b_col; // block pixel = b_p
        columns[b_p] = in_channel[p];
        __syncthreads();

        //Load ends
        float p_val = 0.0f;
        
        for(int i = -k; i < k+1; ++i){
            if((b_col + i) > -1 && (b_col + i) < b_width){
                p_val += gaussian_kernel[k + i] * columns[b_p + i];
            }
            else{
                if((col + i) > -1 && (col + i) < width){
                    p_val += gaussian_kernel[k + i] * in_channel[p + i];
                }
            }
        }
        
        output_channel[p] = p_val;
    }
}
```

The blurring kernel in which shared memory is not used:

```
__global__ 
void gaus_xdirection(float *in_channel, float *output_channel, float *gaussian_kernel, const int width, const int height, int k){
    int row = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    if(row < height && col < width){
        int p = row * width + col;
        float p_val = 0.0f;

        for(int i = -k; i < k+1; ++i){
            if((col + i) > -1 && (col + i) < width){
                p_val += gaussian_kernel[k + i] * in_channel[p + i];
            }
        }
        
        output_channel[p] = p_val;
    }
}
```

Comment: shared memory isn't helping you here, because you still have to load (sometimes) from global memory in your `else` clause.   You should declare a larger shared memory array, and load the boundaries into shared also, and eliminate the need for the `else` clause. Questions asking about performance should provide a [mcve].  Kernels, by themselves, are not a [mcve].

Comment: But why does number of inactive threads increase? Should it be the same since the size of image does not change?

Comment: Any time you have an `if` statement (or other conditional behavior) in your kernel, that can create inactive threads.  Those that satisfy the `if` statement are active, those that don't are inactive (during execution of the `if` clause).  Same is true for `else` statements, and other conditional tests.  Therefore if the conditional structure of your code changes, the measurement by the profiler of inactive threads can change.

Comment: The conditions can be removed if the borders are computed aside. Another strategy is to adapt the input so that there is no need for borders. Note also that the loop can be unrolled for small `k`. With a big `k`, you can use a Fast Fourier transform to speed up the computation a lot.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Is it possible to get the same result by applying Fast Fourier Transform for gaussian blur?

Comment: @Dream Theoretically yes.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are making ineffective use of shared memory.  Replacing a few of the global loads with shared loads is not going to be sufficient.  As a result, your `else` clause:

```
        else{
            if((col + i) > -1 && (col + i) < width){
                p_val += gaussian_kernel[k + i] * in_channel[p + i];
            }
```

is getting invoked too many times, and is drowning out any benefit of shared usage in the `if` clause.

Instead you want to arrange a shared memory tile in such a way that *all* the data can be retrieved from shared memory, after it is properly loaded.

The following is an example of how it could be done (in `gaus_xdirection_shared_i`):

```
$ cat t145.cu

__global__
void gaus_xdirection_shared(float *in_channel, float *output_channel, float *gaussian_kernel, const int width, const int height, int k){
    int row = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    __shared__ float columns[1024];

    int b_row = threadIdx.y;
    int b_col = threadIdx.x;
    int b_width = blockDim.x;

    if(row < height && col < width){
        int p = row * width + col;

        //Load starts
        int b_p = b_row * b_width + b_col; // block pixel = b_p
        columns[b_p] = in_channel[p];
        __syncthreads();

        //Load ends
        float p_val = 0.0f;

        for(int i = -k; i < k+1; ++i){
            if((b_col + i) > -1 && (b_col + i) < b_width){
                p_val += gaussian_kernel[k + i] * columns[b_p + i];
            }
            else{
                if((col + i) > -1 && (col + i) < width){
                    p_val += gaussian_kernel[k + i] * in_channel[p + i];
                }
            }
        }

        output_channel[p] = p_val;
    }
}

__global__
void gaus_xdirection_shared_i(float *in_channel, float *output_channel, float *gaussian_kernel, const int width, const int height, int k){

    int row = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    extern __shared__ float columns[];


    int b_row = threadIdx.y;
    int b_col = threadIdx.x;
    int b_width = blockDim.x + 2*k;

    int p = row * width + col;

        //Load starts
    int b_p = b_row * b_width + b_col+k; // block pixel = b_p
    float temp;
    if( row < height && col < width)
      temp = in_channel[p];
    else
      temp = 0;
    columns[b_p] = temp;
    if (threadIdx.x < k){
          // handle left edge/border
      if (((p-k) >= row*width) && ((p-k) < width*height)) temp = in_channel[p-k];
      else temp = 0;
      columns[b_p-k] = temp;
         // handle right edge/border
      if (((p+blockDim.x) < (row+1)*width) && (row < height))
        temp = in_channel[p+blockDim.x];
      else
        temp = 0;
      columns[b_p+blockDim.x] = temp;}
    __syncthreads();
        //Load ends
    temp = 0.0f;



    for(int i = -k; i < k+1; ++i)
        temp += gaussian_kernel[k+i] * columns[b_p + i];

    if( row < height && col < width)
        output_channel[p] = temp;
}

__global__
void gaus_xdirection(float *in_channel, float *output_channel, float *gaussian_kernel, const int width, const int height, int k){

    int row = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    if( row < height && col < width){

        int p = row * width + col;

        float p_val = 0.0f;



        for(int i = -k; i < k+1; ++i){


            if( (col + i) > -1 && (col + i) < width){

                p_val += gaussian_kernel[k + i] * in_channel[p + i];

            }

        }

        output_channel[p] = p_val;


    }



}

int main(){


  float *in_channel;
  float *output_channel;
  float *gaussian_kernel;
  int width, height, k;
  int th = 32;
  width = 1024;
  height = 1024;
  k = 7;
  cudaMalloc(&in_channel, width*height*sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc(&output_channel, width*height*sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc(&gaussian_kernel, (2*k+1)*sizeof(float));
  dim3 b(th, th);
  dim3 g((width+b.x-1)/b.x,(height+b.y-1)/b.y);
  gaus_xdirection_shared<<<g,b>>>(in_channel, output_channel, gaussian_kernel, width, height,k);
  gaus_xdirection_shared_i<<<g,b,th*(th+2*k)*sizeof(float)>>>(in_channel, output_channel, gaussian_kernel, width, height,k);
  gaus_xdirection<<<g,b>>>(in_channel, output_channel, gaussian_kernel, width, height,k);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t145 t145.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t145
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ nvprof ./t145
==27500== NVPROF is profiling process 27500, command: ./t145
==27500== Profiling application: ./t145
==27500== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:   44.53%  1.0205ms         1  1.0205ms  1.0205ms  1.0205ms  gaus_xdirection_shared(float*, float*, float*, int, int, int)
                   33.35%  764.46us         1  764.46us  764.46us  764.46us  gaus_xdirection(float*, float*, float*, int, int, int)
                   22.12%  506.95us         1  506.95us  506.95us  506.95us  gaus_xdirection_shared_i(float*, float*, float*, int, int, int)
      API calls:   97.88%  141.58ms         3  47.192ms  115.32us  141.22ms  cudaMalloc
                    1.58%  2.2808ms         1  2.2808ms  2.2808ms  2.2808ms  cudaDeviceSynchronize
                    0.36%  514.21us       202  2.5450us     165ns  118.09us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.10%  146.33us         2  73.166us  52.335us  93.998us  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.04%  58.346us         2  29.173us  26.147us  32.199us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.03%  50.393us         3  16.797us  6.9170us  34.369us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.01%  9.5440us         2  4.7720us  1.8600us  7.6840us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  1.3980us         3     466ns     279ns     801ns  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  1.3100us         4     327ns     186ns     712ns  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%     564ns         2     282ns     237ns     327ns  cuDeviceGetUuid
$
```

I have not carefully tested the above code, it may contain defects.  But it should give you an idea of how to structure a larger shared memory tile, and it seems to run without runtime error, and it seems to be faster.

Comment: When I executed it, the shared one runs still slower than normal one which does not contain shared memory. Why did you get such a performance?

Comment: are you building a debug project? (`-G`)

Comment: I am using visual studio 2019 and configuration is set up release and x64

Comment: more information would be necessary then.  If you are running my exact code with no changes whatsoever, then you would need to indicate what kind of GPU you are running on as well as how you are making the determination of run speed.

Comment: Sorry, my graphic card is RTX3060 and I measure the elapsed time with cudaEvent. But I did not understand why did debuggin mode come into your mind firstly? In addition to that, I execute it on Windows 10 Visual studio 2019.

Comment: Perhaps you are simply making an error in your code then.  After all you haven't shown that code.  How would I be able to explain code to you that you haven't shown me?  Regarding debug, for people on windows its a common error to evaluate CUDA performance in a debug project.  The performance (runtime) behavior of CUDA kernels compiled in debug mode can change radically from what is expected in release mode, including a shared memory kernel that is faster than non-shared in release mode but slower than non-shared in debug mode.

Comment: I copied just your code and I ran it in the same way as you did in Colab. Your suggestion runs slower.

Comment: It seems to be dependent on the GPU.  My guess is that the caches on newer GPUs are sufficiently large that they eliminate the need to use shared memory to get the same benefit.

Comment: Then in which cases should shared memory used in such a case?

Comment: Probably with further optimization, shared memory could be faster again. With shared memory you have better control over access patterns and when data is loaded or evicted. Shared memory also helps, when there are many reads and writes on the same data within a block.

Comment: Would you clarify the further optimization method by giving example or sharing resource?

Comment: @Dream This is not so simple. First you have to find out, what the bottleneck is. e.g. with Nsight Compute. Is your kernel bound by memory accesses? Is bad cache utilization the reason? Can this be solved by changing the specific area each block (and thus each multiproc.) works on - e.g. other block/grid configuration, changed for loops? Better coordination of threads belonging to one warp (they do memory accesses at the same time)? What is your typical image size and kernel size? Do x- and y-dimension in one step or one after the other. With shared memory you can finetune those optimizations.

Comment: BTW For optimization or quality purposes blurring is also often done in Fourier space. Then you would use cuFFT for transformation.